# YOAST SEO won't work on custom post type archive

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, seo, customization

I created my custom post type page (archive-objects.php). This page works fine, I have been created page for it and attributed template to it. So everything is okay. But something wrong is with YOAST SEO. This page title, img and other iformation taking from not this page info, but from first looped post in this archive. In my custom post type I done public -> true and has_archive -> true. What problem can this be? Thank you.

Comment: What does your archive template look like?

Comment: It's okay. I solved it. And I leaved comment how I done this. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just find out what I was missing at the top, after get_header();.

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
```

and at the bottom, just before get_footer();

```
<?php endwhile; ?> <?php endif; ?>
```

So I just figured out that I was not loading archive properly, so I don't get all his information.